# UITextField placeholder is in different color when app is localized

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a really weird problem. I have a `UITextField` class with `IBInspectable` var to change it's placeholder color and I'm doing it like this:

```
attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder != nil ?  placeholder! : "", attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color])
```

When the app scheme is set to `System language`, `English` or any language which is `LTR`, it works fine.

But when it's set to Hebrew or any other language which is `RTL`, it doesn't show at all.
However, in the `Debug Hierarchy View` it shows that the `placeholder` is there.

Note that I am setting the translations using the `Localizable.strings` in the `code` instead of the localized storyboards.
Everything works except for `UITextfield`s placeholders

Thanks :)

[image]

EDIT:
Apparently, all that happens is that `attributedPlaceholder` is not taking any effect whatsoever when the app is in LTR mode.
I changed one of the UITextfields background to white, and it shows. Only the `attributedPlaceholder`  & `NSAttributedString`s color doesn't work on RTL mode

Still need a solution though :(

[image]

Comment: Can you show the same view hierarchy for LTR languages?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
extension UITextField{

    override func setLocalized() -> Void {
        if UtilityClass.isLanguageRTL()// check RTL or LTR here {
            self.textAlignment = .right
            self.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
        }
        else{
            self.textAlignment = .left
            self.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
        }
    }

}
```

**In ViewWillAppear**

```
    textField1?.setLocalized()
    textField2?.setLocalized()
```

Comment: Nope :( It doesn't change anything

Comment: How to implement and calling this in your project because this is working fine in my project .

Answer (score 0):

I also occurred the same situation that placeholder fonts were changed after localization (Not only LTR setting).

We had a customized object inherit from `UITextField` and change the color when initialize.

```
@IBInspectable
var placeholderColor: UIColor = UIColor.white {
    didSet {
        attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder ?? "", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: placeholderColor])
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    ....
    attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder ?? "", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: placeholderColor])
    ....
}
```

As using the `Localizable.strings`, we translated the string in `ViewController` as below.

```
    emailTextField.placeholder = "Generic.Textfield.Email".localized
```

However, when changing the string of placeholder didn’t trigger to change placeholder color. Thus, it turns to the default value (R0 G0 B 0.1 A0.22).

We `override placeholder` manually and modify the attributedPlaceholder as the way as we did in the initialization. And FIX !
Hope it can help others as well :)

P.S: Seems Apple fix after iOS 13 but it works for the version before iOS 12.